# Debian 7: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found

Tags: linux, debian

I wanted to play with my friends private on a own Unturned server on my friends VPS with Debian 7. I installed it according to [instructions](https://github.com/RocketMod/Rocket/wiki/Installing-Rocket-on-Linux), but when i start the server, [this show up](http://prnt.sc/c2mycj).

Please help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer

The GNU `libc` library on Debian Wheezy is too old to run the program you need.

### Long answer

1. This widely used standard C library, GNU `libc` ("glibc" for short), tries hard to maintain backward compatibility with old applications while still moving forward in terms of features implemented.
2. To make this possible, it versions its "symbols".

   Symbols are names of functions and variables a library "exports"—makes available to the program code which "links" with the library.
3. Each new version of the GNU `libc` library which gets certain changes
   in the symbols it exports, gains a specific symbol table entry identifying a particula version of this library.  You may think of it as a "handle" to a particular guaranteed feature set provided by this library.

   This is done transparently by the compiler which links a compiled program's code against glibc.
4. Whatever compiler which was used to compile and link your program worked on a system which had glibc 2.15 installed, and so the resulting program now "wants" glibc 2.15 or higher.

Now look at what glibc version my Debian Jessie (8.0) has:

```
$ apt-cache policy libc6
libc6:
  Installed: 2.19-18+deb8u4
  Candidate: 2.19-18+deb8u4
  Version table:
 *** 2.19-18+deb8u4 0
        500 http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
...
```

But if we look at what [Wheezy has](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libc6), we'll see it's 2.13—two point releases "before" the version your program needs.

### What to do about it?

If rebuilding of this program is not possible (I beleive it's not) you have only two options:

- Somehow brinding a newer glibc into the system and making the program "see" it.

  In theory, it should be possible to build a newer glibc, configuring it
  in the process in a way so that it's installed in a non-standard place—such as under `/opt/glibcX.Y` or something like this.

  With a newer glibc version available, you could employ a standard "trick"
  to make your program use the non-standard library: the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable.  Something like this:

  ```
      $ LD_PRELOAD=/opt/glibcX.Y/libc6.so ./myprogram
  ```
- Upgrade your Debian installation.

If you're not too much into building stuff and tinkering with low-level machinery the second option is probably a simpler way to solve the issue at hand.